# Maximally consistent theories have complete countable subtheories in every countable sublanguage.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, model-theory

Given a maximally consistent theory $T$ in a language $L$, show that, for every countable $L_0 \subseteq L$, there is a $T_0 \subseteq T$ that is complete.

I have an attempt at a solution but it doesn't seem to use the countable-ness condition, and seems too easy.

Suppose $L_0 \subseteq L$. Let $T_0 := \{\varphi \in T : \varphi \in L_0\}$. Then for every $\varphi \in L_0$, either $T \cup \varphi$ or $T \cup \neg \varphi$ is consistent, which implies $\varphi \in T$ or $\neg \varphi \in T$ which means $\varphi \in T_0$ or $\neg \varphi \in T_0$ and thus $T \vdash \varphi$ or $T \vdash \neg \varphi$.

This seems too easy however, and it does not use the fact that $L_0$ is countable. Can someone check my proof please? Thank you!

Comment: That is correct - more generally, if $T$ is a maximally consistent $L$-theory and $L_0$ is a sublanguage of $L$, then $T_0:=T\cap L_0$ is a maximally consistent $L_0$-theory. Are you sure you copied the problem correctly?

Comment: This is the exact statement: "Let $T$ be a maximally consistent theory. Show that for every countable $L_0 \subseteq L(T)$ there exists $T_0 \subseteq T$ complete in L0."

Comment: Yeah that's silly. Maybe the instructor/text made a typo? I have no idea.

Comment: The only guess I have: does your text include **satisfiability** as part of the definition of completeness? If so there is a slight difference here: it's easier to prove the completeness theorem for *countable* languages than for arbitrary languages (and indeed the former is provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone while the latter requires some amount of the axiom of choice), and your instructor may be proving the completeness theorem by first proving it for countable theories and then lifting it to arbitrary theories. That'd be really weird, but at least it would be not totally silly.

Comment: Nope we're using $T$ is complete if it's consistent and for every $\varphi$, $T$ proves it or its negation. And $T$ is maximally consistent if it is consistent and has no consistent proper extension. I guess it's just weird then?

Comment: Yeah. Is this an exercise from a text (if so, which text?), or did an instructor whip this one up? If the latter, remember that instructors are human: they may just have had a silly moment.

Comment: I've turned my comments into an answer, based on your responses.

Comment: Recently, there have been a number of questions posted by new users whose usernames are related to the content of the question: in addition to the current one, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822828/what-is-the-general-approach-and-tactics-used-for-ultraproduct-constructions-of) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3818958/number-of-ultrafilters-on-boolean-algebra-of-definable-sets-of-a-countable-stru). Is either of these other questions by you? If so, you should have a single account, rather than making a new throwaway account for each question.

Comment: That's not me sorry.

Comment: In any case, welcome to math stackexchange! I hope you stick around and ask more questions - in which case, you might want to change your user name to something less ... specific :0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem *as phrased* is exactly as simple as it appears. Indeed, you've proved more (as you've observed):

> If $T$ is a maximally consistent $L$-theory then for every sublanguage $L_0\subseteq L$ the subtheory $T\cap Sent(L_0)$ is a maximally consistent $L_0$-theory.

It's worth noting that there is, however, a subtlety which crops up re: countable vs. uncountable languages with respect to **satisfiability**. Namely, the statement "every consistent theory in a countable language has a model" is provable in set theory without the axiom of choice (and indeed we can replace "countable" with "well-orderable"), but the full completeness theorem is not. So the following is a nontrivial theorem:

> $(\mathsf{ZF}$): If $T$ is a consistent $L$-theory and $L_0$ is a countable *(or indeed well-orderable)* sublanguage of $L$, then $T\cap Sent(L_0)$ is satisfiable. Moreover, if $T$ is *maximally* consistent then there is a structure $\mathcal{M}_0$ such that $T\cap Sent(L_0)=Th(\mathcal{M}_0)$.

But it sounds like that's not relevant to what you're doing. I suspect that your instructor made a typo, or had some other kind of silly moment.